# Need to exclude users with no posts from my contributors page

Tags: users

I have a contributors page on my blog that I have recently started and using some code online this is working pretty well.

HOWEVER

I would love it to do two extra things:

1) Only list members who have at least one approved post on the site
2) List the members previous 5 posts

Here is the code I am using currently,

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Authors
*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="clearfix">
<div id="main" class="col620 clearfix" role="main">

<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content post_content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php 

// Get the authors from the database ordered by user nicename
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY user_nicename";
$author_ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);

// Loop through each author
foreach($author_ids as $author) :

// Get user data
$curauth = get_userdata($author->ID);

// If user level is above 0 or login name is "admin", display profile
if($curauth->user_level > 0 || $curauth->user_login == 'admin') :

// Get link to author page
$user_link = get_author_posts_url($curauth->ID);

// Set default avatar (values = default, wavatar, identicon, monsterid)
$avatar = 'wavatar';
?>

<div id="container" style="padding:10px 10px;">
<div class="author single_postmeta">

<a href="<?php echo $user_link; ?>" title="<?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?>">
<?php echo get_avatar($curauth->user_email, '96', $avatar); ?>
</a>

<h3 class="post-title">
<a href="<?php echo $user_link; ?>" title="<?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?>"><?php         echo $curauth->display_name; ?></a><br>

<?php if(get_the_author_meta('jobtitle', $curauth->ID)): ?>
<?php the_author_meta('jobtitle', $curauth->ID); ?> at <?php the_author_meta('company', $curauth->ID); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</h3>
<br>
<p><?php echo $curauth->description; ?> </p>
<br>

<ul>
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('twitter', $curauth->ID)): ?>
<li><a href='http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter', $curauth->ID); ?>'>Follow <?php the_author_meta('first_name', $curauth->ID); ?> on twitter  &rarr;</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('facebook', $curauth->ID)): ?>
<li><a href='<?php the_author_meta('facebook', $curauth->ID); ?>'>Find <?php the_author_meta('first_name', $curauth->ID); ?> on Facebook  &rarr;</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('linkedin', $curauth->ID)): ?>
<li><a href='<?php the_author_meta('linkedin', $curauth->ID); ?>'>Connect with <?php the_author_meta('first_name', $curauth->ID); ?> on Linkedin  &rarr;</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('googleplus', $curauth->ID)): ?>
<li><a href='<?php the_author_meta('googleplus', $curauth->ID); ?>'>Add <?php the_author_meta('first_name', $curauth->ID); ?> to your circle on Google+ &rarr;</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>

</ul>

</div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</article>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Would appreciate any help you can give,

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1):

```
// retrieve latest 5(or all) posts of this user
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'author' => $author,
    'posts_per_page' => 5
));

// skip the user if the number of posts is 0
if($query->post_count < 1)
    continue;

// loop through available posts & display the title
while($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

This code should go inside the  your foreach loop